# Why would a specific Woocommerce REST endpoint return a 503 error only when called through the new API and asking for more than 20 items?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

(**TLDR**: Only ONE endpoint fails, it only fails when called through the new API AND asking for +X number of items)

This Woocommerce store *(not owned by me)* works fine when I make a GET request for 100 items *(the maximum allowed)* to the "orders" and "customers" endpoints, but will return a 503 error when the "products" one is called.

I'm using the latest API, so the call as a URL format would look like:
https://website.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=20
(Btw yesterday it was working ok when asked for 20 items - today the max I can ask for before getting a 503 is 18 items)

The odd thing is that I can ask for 300 items if I call the "old" API like this:
https://website.com/wc-api/v3/products?limit=300

What could the reason for this be?

Comment: This may be unrelated but I'm having a similar issue on Opencart and I've seen that this error has an underlying Apache error that is due to a server timeout. Perhaps you could increase your timeout value and try the request again?

Answer (score 0):

It might a security feature, try to crawl with a header set as "google" and apply setInterval(). Try to iterate not as aloop to go undetected